# Problems displaying text svg tag

Tags: html, text, svg, tags

I have problems with the SVG text tag. This simple code where the coordinate x is set to 20 and the coordinate y is set to 80 works perfect.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <text id="test1" fill="red" x="20" y="80" font-size="30">my text</text>
</svg>
```

The problem comes when I set an actual value of my map to the x and y coordinates like `x=1156291` and `y=661770`. In this case I can not see anything (and i have updated the viewbox to fit the new coordinates).

Trying to find out what is happening I have checked the x and y coordinates of the text tag using java scrip after the SVG is inserted in the DOM and I have discovered that  both have changed (magically) to `-214748.3648`.

Does anyone know what it happening because I am getting crazy...sounds like if there were a problem because the x and y coordinates are too big but I can draw in my map a polyline with that coordinates `(1156291, 661770)` without problems.

Thank a lot for you help

Comment: Could you show us the actual code you're working with? It's impossible to find errors otherwise.

Comment: Browsers are 96dpi, your map(s) are a few thousand dpi. Hence you need to map between (20,80) @ 96dpi vs your map @ thousands-of-dpi

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem under IE9, it seems to be IE9's bug.

for example, 
node is SVGTextElement:

```
var node = svgDocument.getElementById('oneidfortext');

node.setAttribute("x", 39400);
node.setAttribute("y", 394000);
```

then

```
var x = node.getAttribute("x");
var y = node.getAttribute("y");
//x here is going to be 39400
//y here is going to be -214748.3648
```

I have not found solution yet.